# electron configuration on manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, calculus-of-variations, potential-theory, configuration-spaces

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. For $k\geq 2$, suppose there are $k$ particles whose mass and volume can be regarded as zero and negatively charged with electricity **equally**. These $k$ particles move on $M$ freely without frictions and mutually repulse from each  other. When these $k$ particles stop at $(x_1,\cdots, x_k)$ and be stable under small disturbance, we just call $(x_1,\cdots,x_k)$ a "[electron configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration)". The collection of all "electron configuration"s  form the "electron configuration space".

**Question:** Are there any reference about the "electron configuration space"?  What formal names of these spaces should I search online?

**Question:** Any references about the cohomology ring of the "electron configuration space"?

Comment: On a sphere see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem.

Comment: I asked this question a long time ago, for both discrete and continuous charge distributions: http://mathoverflow.net/q/80731/12310 (I originally voted to close as a result, but our questions do seem to differ in the sense that I care about large k where you care about any k).

Comment: Given a fixed $k$, is the solution for stable electron configurations unique up to an isometry of $M$?

Comment: Nope, it's generally far from unique, even on spheres. The first case seems to be 16 points on $S^2$, for which there are (at least) two local optima. As the number of points grows, the number of local minima seems to increase exponentially, but no proof is known. In higher dimensions there are cases with arbitrarily large numbers of non-isometric global minima (the configurations in the last line of Table 1 in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607446).

Comment: The mass of the particles is irrelevant if it's nonzero, since you're asking about a static equilibrium, but if you try to make the mass zero you're going to run into multiple physical issues. In general, you have a lot of description of the dynamics, but the dynamics aren't relevant, and the ones you describe are not consistent with how electromagnetism works. There actually is no consistent theory of the dynamics of a system of point charges. Also, if you want to include all the dynamics, you should not be trying to distinguish between absolute rest and absolute motion.

Comment: You state that you want the equilibrium to be stable, but by Earnshaw's theorem that's not possible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem . Earnshaw's theorem is normally stated in a flat space, but the proof is very simple and AFAICT does not require any assumption about flatness. You simply write down Gauss's law in tensor form, so it holds locally regardless of curvature.

Comment: Another issue you might want to clarify is the dimensionality $n$ of M. If $n\ne3$, then retaining the form of Gauss's law is not consistent with a $-2$ exponent of the Coulomb force law (at short distances -- it doesn't make sense to talk about such a force law at long distances in a curved space). And are you imagining M as having only intrinsic structure, or as being embedded in a higher-dimensional space? If the latter, then Earnshaw's theorem doesn't apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be a considerable body of work on this:

Minimal Riesz energy point configurations for rectifiable d-dimensional manifolds

D.P. Hardin, , E.B. Saff1,

[More by Hardin and Saff.](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~esaff/texts/201.pdf)

http://personales.unican.es/beltranc/archivos/FoCMBeltran2011volume.pdf (Refers to work by Noam Elkies, who will probably have a much more in depth response)

Perhaps most relevant: Papers by Burton Randol and coworkers:

Burton Randol. Stable configurations of repelling points on manifolds. Proc.
Amer. Math. Soc., 142:2769–2773, 2014.

[Nechaeva and Randol](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3804)