# Charge distribution of closed surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, physics

Consider a closed surface $\Sigma$ which bounds a solid $\Omega$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$. Assume some electric charges, say totally $Q$, is distributed on $\Sigma$ and reaches an "equilibrium" state. In this situation the electric field inside $\Omega$ should be $0$.

What can we say about the density $\rho$ of the charge in this equilibrium  distribution? Is there a simple rule that relates $\rho$ to the geometry /curvature of $\Sigma$ (e.g. something like, $\rho$ proportional to the pointwise norm of the second fundamental form - but this is just speculation)? For example, if $\Sigma$ is a round sphere, then it is well known that $\rho$ is constant.

Comment: I don't understand -- what are the dynamics?  Equilibrium of what?

Comment: Equilibrium of the charges: no electrical current.

Comment: Luo Enze. The distribution function of surface charge density with
respect to surface curvature. Journal of Physics D: Applied Physics,
19(1):1–6, 1986

Comment: There is a good bibiography here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09252.pdf

Comment: This is called the equilibrium distribution, and it was very much studied. There is no simple expression in terms of geometry of $\Omega$. Of course it is completely determined by this geometry but the connection is complicated, and most results have the form of inequalities rather than equalities.

Comment: Why on earth would some want to close this question? This is a classic question (not completely solved as far as I can see) that dates back to Maxwell and to an editor's note by J.J. Thomson---the Nobel prize winner who discovered the electron---in Maxwell's treatise. It has been studied for a long time and is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva The argument for closing seems to be that it's unclear or too broad, not that it's off-topic.  I disagree (and did not vote to close), but it's not absurd.

Comment: This question is related, and you might find Henry Cohn's answer there helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80731/minimize-energy-for-charge-distributions?rq=1 .

Comment: The charge density cannot be a function of the second fundamental form, because the problem is global: changing the geometry of the surface in a neighborhood of a point has an effect on the charge distribution everywhere.

Comment: The potential created by the equilibrium charge is harmonic outside of the domain and constant on the boundary of the domain. Thus finding the equilibrium charge is a Dirichlet problem on the complement to a bounded domain. The charge density is the normal derivative of the potential at the boundary points. This [Encyclopedia article](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Potential_theory) gives details and references.

Comment: I voted to close because this question does not belong to research-level mathematics. The author should read some basics of potential theory.